# How to test multi-touch in Android Emulator

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm trying to use multi-touch in an Android 2.0 app.  How can I simulate this with an emulator using Eclipse?  I can only seem to get the mouse to do one touch at a time.

Comment: Your wait is over. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34929298/1739882

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Current version of emulator doesn't support multi-touch.
You need device to do it!

**Update:**

> The emulator supports multi-touch input, as an experimental feature in
>   r17

[Read more](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation)

Comment: Found multitouch support in latest Android Emulator Images, right click and select the center and then do the guesture, Don't know how to disable it for now

Comment: Try pressing Ctr + Z on emulator.

Answer (score 17):

Since ADT 17, it is possible to use a physical Android 4.0 device to send multitouch gestures to the emulator. [See Android's instructions here.](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation)

Answer (score 6):

You can follow [this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5977) on Android's Google code page if you want, but there's currently no support for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old pre-ADT 17 phone, you can still do it.  But the emulator has to be running a recent version of android.

[Here](http://users.tpg.com.au/niknahoo/mobile/sdkcontroller.html) is a compiled version of sdkcontroller app the based on ADT10...