# Is there any way to send multitouch to Android emulator on PC?

Tags: android, gesture

I am doing an project on an Android mobile game. I run the Android virtual device on my PC and now I need to send a three finger touch to the android screen. Could anyone tell me how to implement it? Thanks very much.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation

Comment: Here an older post with almost the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884362/how-to-test-multi-touch-in-android-emulator