# android : remove multi touch from emulator

Tags: android

Today I made following set of updates:

1. updated my Android Studio from 2.0 preview 4 to `2.0 preview 5`.
2. updated my Android SDK tools to `25.0.2 rc3`
3. Updated my Android 6.0 Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image to `Revision 12`
4. Project level dependency to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'`

And what I can see on my emulator is, it has multi touch support :) like simulators of iOS.
Sounds good, but I am not able grab focus on another Window behind it using mouse. Whenever I click window behind that emulator it senses the multi touch input.

[image]

You can see the blue colored circle on my emulator. Is there any way to disable it ?

Comment: @Raptor O god,, :( Is there any solution you are aware of, sir ?

Comment: could you find a workaround? I have the same issue